# Copy a content from one file and need to replace in another file using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, sh

Here, we have two files. we need to copy a key from file 1 and need to replace in file 2 with specific string "key" using sed command. we tried with below commands:

```
sed -e '3 /key/{r file1' -e 'd}' file2

sed  -n "3 s/key/$(cat file 1 |grep ^Key|cut -d ' ' -f2)/" file2
```

**File 1**

```
ABCD
EFGH 
Key: qvUkD6QaFBA1jYEpynivMoQx+9V71F4+fdn1TIUKPBNny/3zCnjihd1mwxZg==
```

**File 2**

```
IJKL
MNOP
secret key;
MNOP
```

**Expected result:**

```
IJKL
MNOP
secret qvUkD6QaFBA1jYEpynivMoQx+9V71F4+fdn1TIUKPBNny/3zCnjihd1mwxZg==;
MNOP
```

Comment: Does it _have to_ be sed? `we need to copy a key from file 1` Don't you want to first _extract_ the key value from file 1? `$(cat file1)` is the _whole file_, not key.

Comment: Great, so see the difference between single and double quotes in shell - you tried single quotes in your sed commands above. Also, it's 3rd line, not 11, and the line contains `secret `, not `key`

Comment: Remote `-n`, so it prints something.

Comment: @KamilCuk, thank you for your response, repost the question correctly! actually line contains `key` next to the secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`awk`**

I am not sure how efficient my code will be for your usage.

```
awk ' /^Key/{q=$2;next} /A|E/{$0=""; next}/^secret/{$2="\""q"\";"}1' $file1 $file2
```

```
$ awk ' /^Key/{q=$2;next} /A|E/{$0=""; next}/^secret/{$2="\""q"\";"}1' $file1 $file2
IJKL
MNOP
secret "qvUkD6QaFBA1jYEpynivMoQx+9V71F4+fdn1TIUKPBNny/3zCnjihd1mwxZg==";
MNOP
```

Here, I am matching any line starting with the `Key` and `secret` string and substituting their values.

**`sed`**

You will need to create a variable to fetch the `key` first.

`key=$(sed '1,2d;s/Key: //' $file1)` or `key=$(awk 'NR==3{print $2}' $file1)`

```
$ echo $key
qvUkD6QaFBA1jYEpynivMoQx+9V71F4+fdn1TIUKPBNny/3zCnjihd1mwxZg==
```

The following code will generate your expected result, but once again, I am not sure how efficient it will be for your usage.

```
sed "/^secret/s|key|$key|" $file2
```

```
$ sed "/^secret/s|key|$key|" $file2
IJKL
MNOP
secret "qvUkD6QaFBA1jYEpynivMoQx+9V71F4+fdn1TIUKPBNny/3zCnjihd1mwxZg==";
MNOP
```

Comment: Thank you! This method worked for us to get perfect result. However, we changed the commands as per mentioned below: 
`key=$(cat file1 |grep ^Key|cut -d ' ' -f2)`
`sed "3 s|key|$key|" file2`

Comment: Happy to hear it worked for you but why `cat` your file first? You could simplify it to `key=$(grep ^Key $file1 | cut -d' ' -f2)` to create the variable.

Comment: Yeah! we will check on it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/Key: /{s///;s/\W/\\&/g;s#.*#s/"key"/&/#p}' file1 | sed -Ef - file2
```

Craft a substitution command from file1 not forgetting to quote non-word characters.

Pass the sed substitution command as `stdin`, to a second invocation of sed via the `-f` option  and use it to edit file2.